# Changing cell values based on table headers and a single column

Tags: string, excel, vba, search

I'm trying to turn certain cells red based on information from a single row and column. What my algorithm is supposed to do is search through the single column and find a matching string and save that the column number, then do the same for the row. Then the script selects the cell and turns it red.

All the keys that I search for come from a piece of code that I found online and modified to suit my needs. It works perfectly. The problem is I can't get the search to work properly.

```
Option Explicit


Sub Blahbot()

Dim xRow As Long
Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim xDirect$, xFname$, InitialFoldr$, xFF$

InitialFoldr$ = "G:\" '<<< Startup folder to begin searching from

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"
    .Title = "Please select a folder to list Files from"
    .InitialFileName = InitialFoldr$
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
        xDirect$ = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        xFname$ = Dir(xDirect$, 7) '<<< Where the search terms come from
        Do While xFname$ <> ""
            y = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Mid(xFname$, 11, 4), Range("D2:KD2"), 0) '<<< Find a matching string in table header
            x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Mid(xFname$, 16, 4), Range("B3:B141"), 0) '<<< Find matching string in column B
            Cells(x, y).Select '<<<Select the cell and turn it red
            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 255
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
            xFname$ = Dir
        Loop
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

What the code does is that it reads through a folder, gets the file names, and splits them up. The name will always be @@@@_#### (where @=upper case letter and #### is a time in 24-hour format).

The Mid function splits that name up into the 4 letters and the time.

If you understand what I'm trying to do, could you suggest a better search algorithm or see what my code is doing wrong?

Comment: Just trying to restate your problem to make sure it is clear.  You are looking for find all cells in a particular range that have a specific set of characters that match the 4 character letter code and 4 digit time code in all filenames that the user selects at the beginning this process?

Comment: What if more than 1 cell has a match?  Do you only want the first one?  Or do you want to match all?

Comment: And some sample data from your spreadsheet might be helpful as well.

Comment: Sorry for the wait. It is guaranteed that only one cell will have a match. I can't upload any specific data because it's classified.

Comment: psubsee2003: The filenames (After I split the 4 letter code and time) are the search keys. The 4 letter code will correspond to a cell in range B3:B141, and the time will correspond to a value in the range D3:KD3. There won't be a case where a certain key won't be found. I made sure that wouldn't be possible.

Comment: @SkylineAddict If you're using `D3:KD3` then that already indicates a problem since your code uses `D2:KD2`. Also, be sure to check your offsets. Look at the values returned by `Match` (`x` and `y`) and see if my answer helps you.

Comment: @Zairja: That was a typo, sorry. I am using D2 and KD2. I responded to your answer below. Let me know what you think and thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified my answer because I may have misunderstood your question. `MATCH` returns a value *relative* to the range you look in. So if the match is in Column D, then `MATCH` returns 1. Therefore, you'll need to offset the returned value.

```
'Add 2 to x, since we start on 3rd row, add 3 to y since we start on 4th column
Cells(x+2, y+3).Select
```

You may also want to include code to check if there is no match. To see if you're having this issue, you can use the code below to test for this or add watches.

```
On Error Resume Next
y = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(...)
If Err = 0 Then
    MsgBox "All is well"
Else
    MsgBox "There was an error with Match"
End If
On Error Goto 0
```

Comment: That helped with the positioning of the squares and I appreciate you clarifying the way MATCH works. Oh, and there will always be a match, so I won't have to worry about that. The problem seems to be with the match function itself, and I think you mentioned something about it before your edit. I get Runtime error 1004: Unable to get the Match Property of the WorksheetFunction class. The script runs through the first 4 columns just fine, then shows that error after.

Comment: @SkylineAddict That error is consistent with `Match` returning `#N/A`. Are you absolutely positive that there will always be a match? I would right-click on `x` and `y` in your VBA editor and add a watch to them to verify this (it'll say that the value is "<Out of context>").

Comment: Yeah, I'm an idiot. I was missing one time column (I constructed the massive spreadsheet by hand and I was too confident in my abilities). After the missing column was added in, it ran for a while longer after quitting thanks to another error by me.